# BigInteger.toByteArray() returning strange value in java

Tags: java, arrays, biginteger

I am experimenting with BigIntegers with random values.

```
BigInteger bi1 = new BigInteger("365375409332725729550921208179070754913983135742");
BigInteger bi2 = new BigInteger("386718480727050819604290866521372728863001258687");

byte[] bytesBi1 = bi1.toByteArray();
byte[] bytesBi2 = bi2.toByteArray();
```

The first one is the one which produces a strange value.
The second is ok.

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong ?

**Edit**

Here're the results:

```
bytesBi1 = [63, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2]
bytesBi2 = [67, -67, 14, 113, -94, 16, -120, 82, 84, 95, -127, -124, -90, -33, 29, -102, 90, 125, -86, -65]
```

Comment: What do you mean with "strange value". Could you please elaborate on that an maybe show some code. Cheers!

Comment: Do you mean it gives negative numbers in the array? If so, this is because the byte in Java is signed byte.

Comment: I edited the post to include the result. I do not understand why bytesBi1 have this value.

Comment: Well, in hexadecimal, the value would be 0x3ffffff(some more ff)fe. What exactly is strange here? This is like numbers of the form `x^2 - 2` for positive x look like.

Comment: @RemiWilde I am very curious. Were did you get the String data for bi1?  What program generated that String?  How did you happen to use that particular sequence of numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BigInteger`'s `toByteArray()` method returns the [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation of the number.

The values you're getting are in fact the correct two's complement representation of the numbers you put in.

Answer (score 0):

This is the hex internal representation of `bi1`, you can see it in the debugger

```
mag[0] = 3FFFFFFF 
mag[1] = FFFFFFFF 
mag[2] = FFFFFFFF 
mag[3] = FFFFFFFF 
mag[4] = 00000001
```

If you split each dwords in 4 bytes and you take the **two's complement** of each bytes,
you get your figures.

eg for the first line : `mag[0] = 3F,FF,FF,FF` wich turns into `63, -1 ,-1,-1` in decimal notation

So nothing wrong with your output.

Answer (score -1):

I tested the given number with my own implementation of arbitrary-precision numbers.
The byte values are completely correct, so it may be simply the case that the random number generator screwed up, is of bad quality or you got some extraordinary outlier.